# Jquery ajax is not sending cookie on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm using jquery ajax and I've read a lot about XDomainRequest on IE9 with CORS, but my case is the following:

I'm on the same origin, so I'm not sending a CORS request and still not sending the cookie with requests.

So the question is that does jquery uses XDomainRequest instead of xmlhttprequest when it detects that's the browser is IE9? Or there's another reason?

Comment: If you are not making a cross-origin request, you should not be using `XDomainRequest`.  Just use `XMLHttpRequest`.  Also, `withCredentials` has no meaning for same-origin requests.

Comment: Right, question edited :)

Comment: Any chance you could add some code to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you are still having this problem, but this answer is for other people coming to this question hoping to find an answer just like I did.

I had the same problem (with IE9 and IE10) and I found out that setting the jquery ajax request to use {cache: false} fixed the problem.

Dion